# Synchronous user dialogs during a long server-side process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a component which imports several files into a large database. The process takes long time, and in many cases can require user dialogs, like "Is this A or is this B? (Button A, Button B)" and so.

The component was written with a desktop application in mind, and now there's a need to migrate this component into an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. The only serious issue I see is to manage these synchronous user dialogs. What's more, by design the synchronous user inputs are sometimes depending on previous user inputs, etc.

I know that synchronous coding "doesn't fit" into the web world at all, but redesigning the whole large algorithm to be somehow asynchronous about user dialogs would be a huge work and would lead to lots of new testing, etc.

Is there any technique which would be applicable in this case without needing to rewrite every user input to asynchronous?

As a note, the operation will be used by very limited users and quite rarely, say 1-2 times a week, so general performance is not an issue.

**What I am thinking about**

1. Start the long operation via an AJAX call, the server would start a new thread and return some token which "points" to the operation.
2. The client-side would poll the server with this token for example in every second if there is new user-input request.
3. When a user input is needed, the operation would wait for X (for example 120) seconds to get an answer, otherwise would cancel itself.
4. If the client-side gets a new user-input request, it will show the dialog, gather the result and send it back to the server, so the operation can continue.

Is this a viable design, or is there any better solution?

Comment: Push events from component to web page using SignalR, and show dialogs you need.

Comment: @Dennis thanks for the comment. Yes I was thinking about SignalR, but that's only one half. I mean SignalR processing on client-side needs to be synchronous as far as I know, so it's not possible to show a custom dialog with callbacks, but correct me if I'm wrong. Still SignalR could be used to explicitly notify the client when a user input is needed, so no polling would be required.

Comment: IMO, you need to build some sort of workflow like this: "start long running process from client -> work ->push notification from server and show dialog -> post user entry and store its results at server-side -> continue process depending on results -> push notification from server and show dialog -> work -> ,,,". Thus, "callback" is a notification from server to query some data from user. If workflow state is stored at server, it knows, what exactly to query.